# How to set or clear the Author in OpenXML SpeadsheetDocument

Tags: c#, openxml

When creating a spreadsheet with the OpenXML SpreadsheetDocument class in C#.Net, the Authors and Last saved by fields are set to "James Westgate".

How do I clear or overwrite James' name?

```
SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true);

doc.PackageProperties.Creator = "sh";
```

...is not working for me.

[image: Props screenshot]

Update:-

```
using System;

using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Extensions;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;

using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

namespace OpenXMLProps
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public MemoryStream Execute()
        {
            MemoryStream stream = SpreadsheetReader.Create();
            using (SpreadsheetDocument doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart = SpreadsheetReader.GetWorksheetPartByName(doc, "Sheet1");
                WorksheetWriter writer = new WorksheetWriter(doc, worksheetPart);

                doc.PackageProperties.Creator = "Finbar mahoolahan";

                SpreadsheetWriter.Save(doc);

                return new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("excel_test.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                MemoryStream excel_stream = Execute();
                excel_stream.WriteTo(fs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After you modify your spreadsheet document, do you do anything to it (i.e., save it out to a file somewhere)?  It would help if you had a full, complete working, but tiny, app that we could see, play with, etc.

Comment: Thanks Flydog. Sorry for the delayed response, I've been on other projects. I've isolated the code and wrapped it in a small WinForms app. How can I upload / share it here?

Comment: Okay, I added my WinForms code to the original post. I'm using Streams, BTW, because in the wild, the Execute() function is the heart of an Excel export / download function for a web application.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (after NuGet-ing in the OpenXml package):

```
using (var doc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(@"C:\tmp\MyExcelFile.xlsx", true))
{
    var props = doc.PackageProperties;
    props.Creator = "Flydog57";
    props.LastModifiedBy = "Flydog57";
    doc.Save();
}
```

It even worked the first time I tried it!  That's an unusual occurrence.

Comment: When I paste this into my project, the doc object () has no Save method.

Comment: That's strange.  I copied that directly from working code.  I'm using v2.81 of the NuGet package: `<package id="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" version="2.8.1" targetFramework="net471" />`.  Here's the associated doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.openxmlpackage.save?view=openxml-2.8.1#DocumentFormat_OpenXml_Packaging_OpenXmlPackage_Save

Comment: Hmmm, the Office 2010 version doesn't have a `Save` method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc535854(v%3doffice.14).  But, the `Close` method is documented that it "Saves and closes the OpenXml package plus all underlying part streams": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc514954%28v%3doffice.14%29

Comment: I just tried the Close method and the resulting spreadsheet was empty after SpreadsheetWriter.Save(doc).

Comment: We're using OpenXML.Extensions which has not been updated for later versions of OpenXML as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

I believe (without looking at the code which is probably 8yrs old by now) that there is a base document which forms the template and this probably has my name associated with it. This is embedded as a resource in the dll.

I suggest trying to download the original *SimpleOOXml* source code from CodePlex and try modifying the document. You could recompile against a modern version of the OpenXML library too.